# GEOSPARQL get the POINTs inside a wkt POLYGON

Tags: gis, sparql, rdf, virtuoso, geosparql

I have an ontology installed on Virtuoso server.

In this ontology I have 2 class:

1. point of interests called POI
2. areas called AREA

Each POI has the relation:

```
{ POI  gis:hasGeometry  ?xx            . 
  ?xx  gis:asWKT        ?WKTexpression }
```

For example, `WKTExpression` can be `"POINT(11.2589271 43.8004469)"^^gis:wktLiteral`

Each AREA has the relation:

```
{ AREA  gis:hasGeometry  ?xx            . 
  ?xx   gis:asWKT        ?WKTexpression }
```

-- where `WKTexpression` is a `"POLYGON()"^^gis:wktLiteral`

How can I extract, with a GEOSPARQL query, all the POI inside a specific AREA?

Can I do something like this?

```
SELECT * 
WHERE 
  {
    ?element  gis:hasGeometry   ?point                          .
    ?point    <IS INSIDE>       "POLYGON(...)"^^gis:wktLiteral
  }
```

==================================

UPDATE 1:
I am trying this query in Virtuoso 7:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
?sensor <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#geometry> ?fWKT .
FILTER (ogcgsf:sfWithin(?fWKT, "POLYGON((11.170005798339842 43.845174931181276,11.157989501953123 43.83130720030931,11.152496337890625 43.82040886498103,11.160392761230469 43.78596696172772,11.172409057617186 43.75745685244749,11.179962158203125 43.74431283565997,11.215324401855467 43.72818887413058,11.244850158691406 43.72694838956602,11.27265930175781 43.74183250878846,11.299781799316404 43.76464763976463,11.331024169921873 43.79166735265696,11.29566192626953 43.824619821317356,11.216697692871094 43.841708300627744,11.172409057617186 43.84888895466105,11.170005798339842 43.845174931181276))"^^geo:wktLiteral))}
```

but I have returned:

```
Virtuoso 42001 Error SR185: Undefined procedure DB.DBA.http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/sfWithin.
```

Comment: Virtuoso-specific questions are often answered more quickly and accurately via Virtuoso-specific resources, like the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the [OpenLink Support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or an [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp). (ObDisclaimer: I am employed by [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)

Comment: The SPARQL query you're trying is incomplete above; there's a `PREFIX` declaration you've left out, which appears to define `ogcgsf:` as `<http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>`. I believe this should be `<http://www.opengis.net/def/geosparql/function/>`...